# SQL Server - Date comparison not working unless date is hardcoded

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am writing a SQL server stored procedure where I am facing some problem on date comparison. The query is not returning any values if I use the variable **@mydate** in the where clause, but it returns if I hardcode the date.

SQL Server query -

```
declare @mydate date = null;
select @mydate  = t1.ResetDate 
from my_table t1 
where ID = 101;

Select * 
from my_another_table t2 
where t2.MyDateRange between @mydate and GETUTCDATE();
```

PS: I have only posted simple query from my stored procedure.

**EDIT**

```
DECLARE
 @ResetDate date = '2018-05-31';     
select * from my_another_table t2     
where t2.MyDateRange>= @ResetDate AND t2.MyDateRange < = dateadd(day, 1, 
cast(GETUTCDATE() as date))
```

In the above query If I hardcode the date value on the where clause its returning values, but if I put @ResetDate it is not returning anything.

Comment: `@mydate = select t1.ResetDate from my_table t1 where ID = 101;` Without SET/SELECT you will get syntax error

Comment: should be `select @mydate = t1.ResetDate from my_table t1 where ID = 101;`

Comment: Hey, thanks. I modified my question. Actually, in the stored procedure it was correct. But only I hardcode the date it is returning values

Comment: What's the value and data type of `my_table.ResetDate`?

Comment: @Kannan also note that there could be multiple t1.ResetDate in my_table

Comment: Well I've removed my answer following the edit.  Are you certain data exists for the the query to populate `@mydate` >

Comment: Value from my_table.ResetDate is 2018-05-31 and it returns only one value and the value is not null

Comment: `IF  EXISTS ( select 1 from my_table t1 where ID = 101) THEN select TOP 1  @mydate  = t1.ResetDate from my_table t1 where ID = 101;`

Comment: I have checked the value and its format. It is type Date and it is returning a value 2018-05-31 from my_table t1. I don't know why this query only returns the value from my_another_table t2 when I hardcode the Date but not if I use @mydate

Comment: Posting the relevant DDL for the two tables and some sample data might help given as the more obvious things appear not to be the issue here

Comment: Try to create a [mcve]. A single script that can start with a couple of table variables, populate them, then something very like the code you're showing us, and indicate what row(s) should be output that aren't.

Comment: Edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

Try not using `between`.  `GETUTCDATE()` -- despite its name -- returns a `datetime`.  For that reason, a structure like this is recommended:

```
declare @mydate date = null;

select @mydate = t1.ResetDate from my_table t1 where ID = 101;

Select *
from my_another_table t2 
where t2.MyDateRange >= @mydate and
      t2.MyDateRange < dateadd(day, 1, cast(GETUTCDATE() as date));
```

Aaron Bertrand has a really good [blog](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) explaining why you don't want to use `BETWEEN` with date/time types.

I should also note that you can express this without using variables (regardless of the date comparison logic):

```
Select t2.*
from my_another_table t2 join
     my_table_t1 t1
     on t2.MyDateRange >= @mydate and
        t2.MyDateRange < dateadd(day, 1, cast(GETUTCDATE() as date))
where t1.ID = 101
```